# How to refer one package as jar in other package?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Pretty new with java/eclipse. Problem: I have two packages in one android project. I want to refer first package as jar to second package. If I will do some changes in first package > after building the project > first package changes should reflect in second package (package1.jar).

Comment: As long as you use `import` you'll be okay... If the changes of the first package made an error in the second package than you must rebuild again the second package.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I want to refer first package as jar to second package"*.

Comment: @ m0skit0 ..When I will compile my project, first package should export as jar and that latest jar should be refer in second package. This overall process I want to do.

Comment: @Crazenezz .. While importing in second package how to import first package as jar ?

Comment: @Raghav are you sure you want to make one project a jar?  it will mean no access to any of the resources on the Library project.  Instead you can just set up the library project as a library and include in the other project.  This way you get resources goodness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Eclipse as your IDE, just create a folder named `lib` and put all your jars in that folder. After that import all the jars as libraries.

```
Right Click on your project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add JARs...
```

[image: Import Libraries Picture]

*Note : If rebuild your first package make an error for your second package than you must rebuild the second package.*